# How to remove gitbook editor?

Tags: uninstall, cinnamon

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 with the Cinnamon desktop (I can't stand Unity). I use the laptop mostly for browsing and for amateur astronomy. Unexpectedly, i found myself needing a markdown editor and I tried a few. I settled for Atom and removed the others... Except for Gitbook, that I seem to e unable to remove.

Gitbook installed with a terminal script but is not listed with all the other programs. Synaptic does not see it and a `sudo apt-get remove gitbook` returns a program not found answer. There was no removal script. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rm -r ~/.gitbook
```

The desktop entry and menu item:

```
xdg-desktop-menu uninstall friendcode-gitbook.directory friendbook-gitbook.desktop
xdg-desktop-menu forceupdate
```

Answer (score 4):

If you installed ***.deb** package it should work:

```
sudo apt-get remove gitbook-editor
```